# Problem using recoloring algorithm from a paper

Tags: python, image, colors

I want to implement a recoloring algorithm from a [paper (P.18)].[1](http://sharif.edu/%7Ekasaei/Papers/CT_JVCI_06.pdf)

I implemented the algorithm with the following function:

```
def color_transfer_arash(I1, I2):
ShowImage(I1, title="I1")
ShowImage(I2, title="I2")
pca_I1 = PCA(n_components=3)
pca_I2 = PCA(n_components=3)

I1_shape = I1.shape
I2_shape = I2.shape

I1_length = I1_shape[0] * I1_shape[1]
I2_length = I2_shape[0] * I2_shape[1]

I1 = I1.reshape(I1_length, 3)
I2 = I2.reshape(I2_length, 3)

principal_components_I1 = pca_I1.fit(I1)
principal_components_I2 = pca_I2.fit(I2)

V1 = np.matrix(principal_components_I1.components_)
V2 = np.matrix(principal_components_I2.components_)

n1 = principal_components_I1.mean_
n2 = principal_components_I2.mean_

for i in range(0, I1.shape[0]-1):
    I1[i] = np.add(np.dot(np.dot(V2, np.matrix.transpose(V1)), np.subtract(I1[i], n1)), n2)

n1_ = I1.mean(0)
print("I2 mean:  " + str(n2))
print("I1_ mean: " + str(n1_))
I1 = I1.reshape(I1_shape)

ShowImage(I1, title="I1'")
return I1
```

I am using the same images as used in the paper, but I get a completly different result. To check my code, I print the mean color of my target image (I2) and the mean color of my recolored source image (I1_), as they should be the same after the recoloring:

```
I2 mean:  [162.59123435  97.34883721 242.55366726]
I1_ mean: [162.07958993  96.85195713 158.7473439 ]
```

As you can see, the first two colors match, but the last one doesn't. (Note: I am using opencv, therefore the colors are in bgr format)

This is my thrid day searching my error, so hopefully someone can help me out.
Thanks a lot!